# shadowed field does not get set in base class constructor

Tags: c#

Why is it that when I set a shadowed field (declared using `new` keyword) in a base class constructor, the field that was shadowed gets set but not the field that is shadowing?

I thought that `this.GetType()` referred to the outermost class all the way down into base class calls including the constructor. I also thought that shadowing made the shadowed field not accessible.

In my quick watch I can see two fields, the shadowed one that got set and the shadowing one (of the subclass) that is still not initialized.

I fixed it by explicitly setting the shadowing field in the subclass constructor after it calls the base class constructor, but I'd still like to know why it acts this way. [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwVDYM)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass(2);
        Console.WriteLine(subClass.MyField);
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(int value)
    {
        MyField = value; // This doesn't point to SubClass.MyField
    }

    public int MyField;
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(int value):base(value)
    {

    }

    public new int MyField = 4;

}
```

**Update**

After reviewing the answers, I see I didn't ask what I wanted to know in the most direct way. Sorry for any inconvenience. Here's what I really want to know:

I do understand shadowing. I don't agree with it. I don't think it should be allowed for fields (as long as overridable fields were made a language feature). I don't see the point in shadowing fields and having the shadowed field hanging around. I do however see the point in overridable fields and I don't understand why that language feature doesn't exist when it exists for properties and methods. So, why have shadowing on fields? Why is there not overriding on fields?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you'd *show* the code rather than *describing* it. Basically, fields aren't polymorphic - the base class constructor only knows about the base class field, and can only read/write it. I suspect that explains everything you're seeing, but it's hard to tell from just your description.

Comment: "I also thought that shadowing made the shadowed field not exist." I don't know what you mean by that, or where you got that idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ok I'll add some code. I meant that the shadowed field was inaccessible because it was superseded; effectively re-declared in the subclass. Your reputation is 861k; my argument is invalid :-)

Comment: Regarding your update: is this a question, or is it a rant about the choices of the language designers?

Comment: @EricLippert, not so much a rant as a feature suggestion. But I read your answer and I'm not about to dream I'm smarter than the c# developers in my ideas. So I'll just study what it does and try to understand to the best of my ability.

Comment: Well, start where I suggested you start. Shadowing as it is implemented in C# is in part a mitigation for the brittle base class family of program failures. A good place to begin there is to consider the question "why is `new` optional, but produces a warning if omitted?" Consider three organizations, none with access to each other's code, one providing Animal, one providing Mammal, and one providing Giraffe. How can they accidentally break each other? How does `new` mitigate those failures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have

> I also thought that shadowing made the shadowed field not accessible.

Followed by

> I do understand shadowing.

I'm not entirely sure that you do. You've already expressed one false belief about shadowing; how do we know there aren't more?

> I don't agree with it.

Your opinion is noted.  I note that you are not required to use the feature if you don't like it.

> I don't think it should be allowed for fields (as long as overridable fields were made a language feature).

Noted.

> I do however see the point in overridable fields and I don't understand why that language feature doesn't exist when it exists for properties and methods.

Fields should be private implementation details of classes.  If they are, then there is no accessible name to shadow or override, so the problem is moot. A feature that we would want no one to use is a bad feature.

> So, why have shadowing on fields?

Suppose there is a protected field in a derived class. Now consider the brittle base class problem. Work through a number of such scenarios; *you're critiquing a language design choice, so think like the language designers think*. What do you conclude from your investigation into typical brittle base class scenarios?

> Why is there not overriding on fields?

Because (1) we have no mechanism for overriding fields; methods have vtables but there is no vtable mechanism for fields. And (2) fields should be private implementation details of classes, and therefore there is never a need to override them.  If you want to override a field, make a property that wraps it and override that.  The code change is *tiny* to go from a field to a virtual property.

Fields should be in the mechanism domain of the class; properties are in the business domain. Specialization of behaviour belongs in the business domain.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public class BaseClass
> {
>     public BaseClass(int value)
>     {
>         MyField = value; // This doesn't point to SubClass.MyField
>     }
>
>     public int MyField;
> }
> ```

The base class doesn't know about its derived types. `MyField = value` does exactly what it says it's doing: it assigns `MyField` with `value`.

> ```
> public class SubClass : BaseClass
> {
>     public SubClass(int value):base(value)
>     {
>
>     }
>
>     public new int MyField = 4;
>
> }
> ```

Are you expecting the value `4` to propagate to the base type? Your question is quite hard to answer, because it's not exactly clear what your definition of "intuitive" and expectations are.... and your example code is very poor OOP design.

There aren't lots of valid reasons to ever expose a `public` field, base class or not.

Let me rephrase your example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private int _value;
    public virtual int Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(int value) : base(value)
    {

    }

    public new int Value { get; set; } // hides base class member
}
```

Now. `SubClass.Value` is its own thing - if you want to access the value that was passed down the constructor, you need to do so via the base class.

The base class member doesn't "cease to exist", it's only *hidden*, or *shadowed*, by a new member in a derived type, that just so happens to have the same identifier:

```
var foo = new SubClass(42);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Value);
Console.WriteLine(((BaseClass)foo).Value);

Console.ReadKey();
```

This code outputs `0`, then `42` - because when `foo.Value` gets accessed the `SubClass` says "hey base class, let me handle this - I have my own definition of `Value`, and this call mine to pick up." ...and returns `0` because, well, it's never actually assigned; the `42` is only visible via the base class.

*That* is what *member shadowing* does.

And it works the same even without the `new` keyword - the `new` keyword merely suppresses a compiler warning that says "you're hiding a base class member here, *are you really totally completely sure you intend to be doing this?*" - because in a normal world, that typically isn't what you would want to be doing.

Now, notice I made the `Value` property `virtual`. What happens if you `override` it instead?

```
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(int value)
        : base(value)
    {

    }

    public override int Value { get; set; } 
}
```

The little console program above (a few snippets up) will now output `0` and `0` - because the subclass' `Value` *overrides* the base class member, effectively telling C# to resolve member calls to the derived type. So to output the `42` you're passing in, *because you're overriding the member*, you become responsible for how it works - the `_value` private field in the base class still says `42`, but the `Value` property being overridden, the field is left unused.

So you assign it in your derived type's constructor (here sealing the class to avoid a virtual member call in the constructor):

```
public sealed class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(int value)
        : base(0)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override int Value { get; set; } 
}
```

So, here the derived type is passing `0` to the base class, and overriding the member. What does the little snippet output for `42` now?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new SubClass(42);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(((BaseClass)foo).Value);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

> it will output 42 for both the derived and the downcasted calls, because the type cast is now redundant, since the virtual member is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but here is how :

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(int value)
    {
        SetValue(x => x.MyField, value);
    }

    public int MyField;

    public void SetValue<TField>(Expression<Func<BaseClass, TField>> memberSelector, TField value)
    {
        var expression = memberSelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expression == null)
            throw new MemberAccessException();

        this.GetType().GetField(expression.Member.Name)
            .SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to clarify what I'm really asking here. Sorry for any inconvenience. I didn't want to reverse the roles of base and sub class, as you do here. I just didn't know why the subclass code didn't handle my expectations.

Comment: Please, do not drastically change you question when it already has some answers (+an accepted one) and when an hour has already past. With that being said, your question is duplicated post. See : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/153738/what-are-some-practical-uses-of-the-new-modifier-in-c-with-respect-to-hiding

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that shadowing a field just makes a new field, it is in no way related to the field in the base class (except by virtue of the fact that you've given it the same name).

Simply put, you haven't written any code that sets the field in `SubClass`, you've only written code that sets the field in `BaseClass`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(int value)
    {
        MyField = value; // This doesn't point to SubClass.MyField
    }

    public int MyField;
}
```

`MyField` here can only ever refer to the `MyField` in `BaseClass`.  It can't possibly know that you're going to create a subclass later and put a field in it with the same name.  And even if you do that, all you've done is create a different field with the same name, so why would setting `BaseClass.MyField` also set the mostly unrelated `SubClass.MyField`?